# Interesting behaviour when reassigning $this

Tags: php, class, this

I adapted a very simple `View` class to pass variables from `Controller` to `View` so that in the `View` I can call the variables directly e.g.

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

and not

```
<?php echo $this->name; ?>
```

All the view vars are stored in an associative array called vars e.g. `$vars['name'] = "test"` and have `__set` function setup to assign vars e.g.

```
$v = new View;
$v->name="test";
$v->out();
```

So in the `out()` function which passes the variables and includes the view HTML I added:

```
    foreach($this->vars as $key=>$val) {
      $$key=$val;
    }
include $this->view_file;
```

I then tested what would happen if I used `$this` in the template and added a corresponding variable like

```
$v->this = "test_this";
```

My assumption was that either the code will fail because `$this` cannot be reassigned or that even if it reassigned - [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#107080) - the code will fail because `$this` has been reassigned so

```
include $this->view_file;
```

won't work!

Instead, it worked.
`$this`, when called directly either using `echo $this;` or `var_dump($this);` equals `"test_this"` but `$this->view_file` still points to the original value!!

**How can this be?**

I then retested using `extract($this->vars, EXTR_OVERWRITE)` and `$this` didn't get touched!

In general, what would be the right approach to pass variables to the view and avoid collisions in the function

```
function out($view, $toString = false)
{
    extract($this->vars);
    include $view;
}
```

and vars might have a var called view or "this" or maybe the template will use the `$view` var.

1. Don't worry, just make sure not to assign a var called view.
2. Use long variable names in `out()` function, like `$longVarNameSoThatThereWillNotBeCollisions`.
3. Assign all vars that are needed for function to `$this->temp`: `$this->temp['view']` and then `unset($view)` - and as for `$this` - who in their right mind would use a variable called `$this` in `View`!

Comment: Is there a question in all of this, or are you just ranting?

Comment: Thanks for fixing formatting - I was in the middle and you got there first!     The Question is How can $this point to "test_this" and $this->view_file points to "view.html.php"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain why you are still able to access an objects properties, even though you've managed to circumvent the protection of reassigning `$this`, you have to look at the opcodes generated for the compiled script.

Object properties are accessed using the `FETCH_OBJ_R` opcode.

When you write code such as

```
$myObject = new testClass;
$myObject->property
```

The compiled code generates `FETCH_OBJ_R` with **two** parameters. The first is the variable containing the object, and the second is the name of the property.

If you use the Vulcan disassembler, the output might look like the following:

```
FETCH_OBJ_R                                      $1      !1, 'property'
```

`$1` is where the return value is stored, and `!1` is the variable containing the object.

However if you access the property using `$this` the generated output is slightly different.

```
FETCH_OBJ_R                                      $1      'property'
```

The opcode with one parameter resolves the property lookup to the object from within which it was called.

So the answer to your question, `$this->property` was resolved at compile time. Even though you broke `$this`, the location of `property` had already been decided.

Comment: Thanks! What about the other (implied) question : why does $this only get overwritten by $$key=$val and not by extract()? My assumption is simply that the extract function checks that it shouldn't overwrite $this - maybe you(as lowlevel programmer) can have a look in php source to check

Comment: @neyl: `extract` specifically checks for `this` (and `GLOBALS`). You can check the source under [`ext/standard/array.c`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#1394)

Answer (score 0):

This interested me a bit and it seems you're right, there may well be a bug when using variable-variable assignment to `$this`.

As you rightly said:

```
<?php
$var = 'this';
$$var = 'hello';

echo $this;
```

works, whereas

```
<?php
$this = 'hello';

echo $this;
```

doesn't.

Perhaps report it on bugs.php.net and see if there's an official answer to this?

The fact that the existing members of `$this` still work whilst the actual value of `$this` is something entirely different should definitely not be happening and must be some form of core issue. The only thing I could think of is that somehow `$this` is being used as a magic context variable (of course not surprising, it is PHP afterall!) and not an actual 'real' variable. The bug of assignment from a variable-variable (which should obviously **not** happen!) allows the fact that `$this` is a faux-variable to be displayed to the developer.

Magicness test:

```
<?php

class ThisTest {
    public function SetAndUseThis() {
        $var = 'this';
        $$var = 'that';
        var_dump($this);
        var_dump($this->variable);
        var_dump($this->AnotherMethod());
    }

    public $variable = 'i am a variable';

    public function AnotherMethod()
    {
        return 9.0;
    }
}

$inst = new ThisTest();
$inst->SetAndUseThis();
```

Results in:

```
string(4) "that" string(15) "i am a variable" float(9)
```